# Regex - 2 capturing groups in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have this bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

contents=`echo "$(<testdoc.xml)"`

regex='(?<=name=")(.+)">(.+)(?=<\/block)'

for line in $contents
do
        [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
        blockname="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        blockversion="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

        echo $blockname
        echo $blockversion
done
```

testdoc.xml contents are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DomainManifest>
  <blocks>
    <block name="WPF">WPF-13 31.10.2012 / 09:06:55</block>
    <block name="VSH">VSH-08 30.10.2012 / 09:12:06</block>
    <block name="VBN">VBN-14 15.06.2015 / 13:29:16</block>
    <block name="RMV">RMV-27 07.07.2015 / 10:52:57</block>
    <block name="ZRL">ZRL-12 01.07.2011 / 09:23:25</block>
    <block name="NPH">NPH-05 07.07.2008 / 09:36:32</block>
    <block name="VDV">20150630</block>
    <block name="VerbundMetaInfo.properties">22.06.2015</block>
  </blocks>
</DomainManifest>
```

When I try out the regex on https://regex101.com/ with said contents it works like a charm. What am I doing wrong? 
Must be something in my bash no?

**edit:**

Script now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex='(?<=name=")(.+)">(.+)(?=<\/block)'

while read line
do
    echo $line

    [[ $line =~ $regex ]]

    blockname="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    blockversion="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

    echo $blockname
    echo $blockversion
done <$1
```

which at least returns the lines correctly, yet the regex is not returning anything. Any ideas?

**edit2:**

Got it working with grep and 2 separate regexes:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex_name='(?<=name=")(.+)(.+)(?=">)'
regex_version='(?<=">)(.+)(?=<\/block)'

while read line
do
    echo $line | grep -oP $regex_name
    echo $line | grep -oP $regex_version
done <$1
```

Comment: Check out this script 

    `#!/bin/bash -e  
    contents=\`echo "$(<testdoc.xml)"\`   
    for line in $contents  
    do  
        echo "line: $line"  
    done`

When I executed it, the output looks like this:
`line: <?xml  
line: version="1.0"  
line: encoding="UTF-8"  
line: standalone="yes"?>  
line: <DomainManifest>  `  
And so on...
For some reason every space is interpreted like new line character

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) explains why you need the `while` loop version. I don't believe that regex is valid in bash. That site is showing you PCRE/etc. but bash uses ERE (extended regular expressions).

Comment: thanks, you're right. On this site: http://regexraptor.net/ the regex doesnt validate. Need to dig into the differences of both implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Bash, for loops on strings split on spaces, unless you engage in quoting, which isn't appropriate for this file input.  What you want instead is more like:

```
while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
    blockname="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    blockversion="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

    echo $blockname
    echo $blockversion
done <testdoc.xml
```

Good luck!

Comment: marked as an answer since it solved my initial problem using the wrong method to read a file. The issue with the different regex implementations I stumbled upon afterwards is solved as "edit 2" within the original post for documentaton.